# Fifteen minuter? Give it a shot

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Exactly one of the seven tiles on the bottom will go in each of the seven curved regions formed by the overlapping circles. Two additional tiles have been placed for you - but the question is which tiles go where and why?

[image]

Comment: I think I've got ROT13{HF cerfvqragf (Gehzc, Bonzn, Zbaebr, Ebbfriryg, Erntna)} and ROT13{fhowrpgf bs Jneuby neg (Zbaebr, Ryivf, pnaf, Jneuby)}, but not sure about the third category or the last member of the second one. The second category would also fit with the first half of the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can resolve this Venn diagram:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

The three ellipses represent:

> Top left: **Surnames of US Presidents**
>
>   (James) **Monroe**, (Barack) **Obama**, (Ronald) **Reagan**, (Theodore/Franklin) **Roosevelt**, (Donald) **Trump**
>
>
>  Top right: **Andy Warhol artwork subjects**
>
>  Campbell's Soup **Cans**
>  [image: Campbell's Soup Cans]
>
>  **Elvis** Presley
>  [image: Elvis 1 & 2]
>
>  Marilyn **Monroe**
>  [image: Marilyn Monroe]
>
>  Teddy **Roosevelt**
>  [image: Teddy Roosevelt 386]
>
>  Andy **Warhol** himself!
>  [image: Warhol self-portrait]
>
>
>  Bottom: **Shot in failed assassination attempts**
>
>  [Pope **John Paul II**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attempted_assassination_of_Pope_John_Paul_II), [Ronald **Reagan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attempted_assassination_of_Ronald_Reagan), [Theodore **Roosevelt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attempted_assassination_of_Theodore_Roosevelt), [Andy **Warhol**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valerie_Solanas)
>
>
>  The name appearing in all 3 categories is thus 'Roosevelt' - what a colourful life!

Re the title:

> Andy Warhol once said that one day everybody would be 'famous for *fifteen minutes*', and 'shot' suggests *gunshots*.